# What does this solution mean?

Tags: functions, proof-verification

I have recently learnt about functions. While I was solving a problem, I didn't know how to solve it. So I referred to the solution however I couldn't understand what it was talking about.

In this website (https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=1997_AIME_Problems/Problem_12), you can see both the question and the solution. I was looking at solution 1 and it said.

> From $c(a + d) = b(a + d) = 0$, we get $a = - d$ or $b = c = 0$. The
>   second cannot be true, since we are given that $a,b,c,d$ are nonzero.
>   This means $a = - d$, so $f(x) = \frac {ax + b}{cx - a}$. The only
>   value that is not in the range of this function is $\frac {a}{c}$

Can someone please explain to me what the solution means? Specifically, I don't get how they got $a = - d$ or $b = c = 0$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a product of two real numbers, say $x\cdot y$ is equal to $0$, then $x=0$ or $y=0$ (or both).

Now in your case, we have $c(a+d)=0$ and $b(a+d)=0$.

*Case 1*: $a+d=0$. Then $d=-a$.

*Case 2*: $a+d\neq 0$. Then $c=0$ and $b=0$.

Comment: Also, in the solution (Look at solution 1 of [this website](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=1997_AIME_Problems/Problem_12)) it says **In order for this fraction to reduce to $x$, we must have $q = r = 0$ and $p = s\not = 0$**. Why is this so?

Comment: $$\frac{px+q}{rx+s} = x \;\;\Leftrightarrow \;\;\ px+q = x(rx+s) = rx^2+sx$$
Now compare coefficients: $x^2$ term: $0=r$, $x$ term: $p=s$, constant term: $q=0$.